# Keep the wheels/gears of the company running/turning

Tags: idiomatic-language

Which of these combinations are possible? Which one do you prefer?

1. It is your hard work that keep the wheels of the company running.
2. It is your hard work that keep the wheels of the company turning.
3. It is your hard work that keep the gears of the company running.
4. It is your hard work that keep the gears of the company turning.

Comment: I would avoid using "gears".  There is a negative simile: "to feel like a [**cog in the machine**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-cog-in-a-the-machine)," which means that at an employee feels unimportant and easily replaceable.  A [cog](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cog) is the tooth of a gear.

Comment: The intended meaning is "It is your hard work that *keeps* the company running.", which is clear and concise. The metaphor isn't needed, and most employees don't care to be compared to a common inanimate object anyway. In addition, "work" is singular.

Answer (score 0):

I would say

> It is your hard work that keep the wheels of the company turning.

The idiomatic phrase is [***to keep the wheels turning***](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/keep-the-wheels-turning), but I have heard [***rolling***](https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/keep-the-ball-rolling#:%7E:text=Keep%20the%20Ball%20Rolling%20Meaning,rather%20than%20stall%20or%20stop.) as well. "rolling" is less formal than "turning" though.

Having said that, the expression [***to keep the gears turning***](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/keep-the-wheels-turning) does exist, and it is probably a matter of choice. In my opinion, "wheels" bring more "dynamics" to the meaning, but my assumption may be subjective.